# Understanding "sending hex code"

Tags: iterm

Recently I've installed iTerm2 and customized key mappings.

For example, I wanted <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove the entire line. In order to achieve this I created a new key mapping where <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> maps to `Send hex codes: 0x15`.

Could someone point me to the source where it is explained what sending hex code actually achieves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just sends the corresponding bytes to the shell. Same thing as "send escape sequence" but with different notation - the raw data otherwise represented by symbols and characters. It's then up to the shell to interpret this (usually through `readline` and `.inputrc` bindings, or equivalent) into commands.

In your specific example, `0x15` means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, the standard binding for `backward-kill-line`. So when you bind <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to send that, it works because you are just piggybacking on the standard bindings.